# Which pairs of matrices generate $SL(2, \mathbb{Z})$?

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory

I am trying to understand 2 element generating sets of $SL(2, \mathbb{Z})$ certainly these two:

$$ 
\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{array}\right) \text{ and }
\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1\end{array}\right)$$

The [Groups Wiki suggests](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Special_linear_group:SL%282,Z%29) we can replace $1$ and $1$ with $a$ and $b \in \mathbb{Z}$.

$$ 
\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & a \\ 0 & 1\end{array}\right) \text{ and }
\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ b & 1\end{array}\right)$$

This doesn't seem quite right, for example if $a,b = 0$.  However if $a, b \neq 0$ and $(a,b) = 1$ maybe it can be true.

---

I wonder if there are more examples even more different than these

Comment: Wiki doesn't say that $\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & a \\ 0 & 1\end{array}\right) \text{ and }
\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ b & 1\end{array}\right)$ generate $SL(2,\mathbb Z)$. Instead, they say (misunderstandably) that the set $\left\{\,\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & a \\ 0 & 1\end{array}\right):a\in\mathbb Z\,\right\} \cup
\left\{\,\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ b & 1\end{array}\right):a\in\mathbb Z\,\right\}$ generates it

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen thank you.  I know $a = b = 1$ is enough to generate all of $SL(2, \mathbb{Z})$ and hopefully there are many others.

Comment: One you've found one pair $M,N \in SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ which generate, you can get infinitely many other pairs by conjugation. More generally, in any group $G$, given any set $\{g_i\}$ of generators, and given any $h \in G$, the set $\{h^{-1} g_i h\}$ is also a generating set.